# Excel Conditional Format Duplicate Values

Tags: excel

Im struggling to find an answer to this. I want to find duplicates in column B when column G is not "N/A" Using a conditional format to make column b red

here is some example data

```
Server Name(col B), NAT (Col G) 
MYSERVER, N/A <---- should not be checked
MYSERVER, N/A <---- should not be checked
MYSERVER, 10.10.10.10 <----- SHOULD BE CHECKED
MYSERVER, 10.20.20.20 <----- SHOULD BE CHECKED
MYSERVER1, 1.1.1.1 <---- shouldnt be checked
MYSERVER1, N/A <---- shouldnt be checked
```

Obviously from this the top 2x records shouldn't be checked for duplicates, the next 2x records should be checked as the dont say N/A, the last 2 records shouldnt be checked as there is no duplicate (due to one record having N/A)

Comment: Your question isn't clear please explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the formula you need is this:-

```
=AND(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,G:G,"<>N/A")>1,G2<>"N/A")
```

That will only include duplicates if there is more than one row with the same server name but not with 'N/A' in column G, and also exclude any individual row that has 'N/A' in column G.

Use it in conditional formatting in range B2:B7 (I have also used it separately in G2:G7) with the 'Use a formula' option.

If your N/A's are #N/A error values, you'll need to use the ISNA function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I tried Toms formula above it wouldn't work as a conditional formatting rule, if you amend it to this (assuming G2 is your header):

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B4,$G:$G,"<>N/A")>1,$G2<>"N/A")
```

It should work,
if you have more than about 300 rows, excel will get very slow, if it does create a hidden column with that forumla and set your conditional formula to:

```
=$J=TRUE
```

Comment: I think my formula was OK if you just applied it to one column as requested by OP, but if you tried to copy it across multiple columns you would need the dollar signs.

Comment: I found that issue if i applied to whole table or just a column.

Comment: Have provided screenshot - it worked for me when applied separately to ranges B2:B7 and G2:G7